# Using UNNEST with column from with_query_name (WITH clause) table

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting the following error

> (100032) Error executing query job. Message: Unrecognized name: nested

where `nested` is my temporary table declared as a WITH clause. Attempted code is as follows:

```sql
WITH nested AS
(
  SELECT e.my_id , SPLIT(secondary_ids, '<#>') AS arr_secondary_ids
  FROM table_with_delimited_string_column e
  WHERE my_id = 1234
)
SELECT DISTINCT a
FROM  UNNEST(nested.arr_secondary_ids) a
```

The SPLIT function would return a type ARRAY, which later would be UNNESTed.

From the Google Cloud documentation, this works:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y STRING>>[(1, 'foo'), (3, 'bar')]);
```

This also works:

```sql
WITH sequences AS
  (SELECT 1 AS id, [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5] AS some_numbers
   UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS id, [2, 4, 8, 16, 32] AS some_numbers
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS id, [5, 10] AS some_numbers)
SELECT id, flattened_numbers
FROM sequences
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(sequences.some_numbers) AS flattened_numbers;
```

So, technically, value tables resulting from UNNEST should be able to be queried directly from a `SELECT *`. Also, columns from temporary tables should be able to be UNNESTed.

However, when I go back to my use case, the `...UNNEST(nested.arr_secondary_ids)` will produce the aforementioned error.

I'd like to be able to query it straight away since I'm getting duplicate values on the resulting table, which as you can see I want to get rid of with the `DISTINCT`. What is the current work around and what would be the technical reason this error is being produced? Would like to know if it's something related  with ARRAY or STRUCT types that I'm missing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Previous answers have contributed greatly to understand why `nested` is required. However, I have found optimal scenarios for when the primary key (a.k.a `my_id`) matters to define duplicates and when it doesn't.

In my real scenario, `my_id` matters and I don't want repeated pairs of `my_id`, `secondary_id`. There is no way of avoiding the `CROSS JOIN` or multiple table referencing, as the source CTE table has to be in the FROM clause directly (as mentioned by [@pruthvi-kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10019687/pruthvi-kumar) and [@mikhail-berlyant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221944/mikhail-berlyant)). [@mikhail-berlyant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221944/mikhail-berlyant) has also pointed out that it's just a flattening operation so `CROSS JOIN` is also not an expensive operation here. All in all, the solution would be:

```sql
WITH nested AS
(
  SELECT e.my_id , SPLIT(secondary_ids, '<#>') AS arr_secondary_ids
  FROM table_with_delimited_string_column e
)
SELECT DISTINCT nested.entity_id, a
FROM nested CROSS JOIN UNNEST(arr_secondary_ids) a
```

However, in the posted question, I had stated a fixed `my_id` = 1234, hence this column wouldn't be a determining factor of duplicates. In this scenario, the correlated cross join can be skipped by using a scalar subquery for the arrays to be unnested. Here the optimal solution would be:

```sql
WITH nested AS
(
  SELECT e.my_id , SPLIT(secondary_ids, '<#>') AS arr_secondary_ids
  FROM table_with_delimited_string_column e
  WHERE my_id = 1234
)
SELECT DISTINCT a
FROM UNNEST((SELECT arr_secondary_ids FROM nested)) AS a
```

Note the parentheses wrapping the SELECT inside the unnest. They're required as otherwise you would get a message like:

> The argument to UNNEST is an expression, not a query; to use a query
>   as an expression, the query must be wrapped with additional
>   parentheses to make it a scalar subquery expression

`nested` should also have only 1 row after the `my_id` filtering, otherwise you will find a nasty

> Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Answer (score 3):

Using `UNNEST` in a statement following CTE is not valid. A [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, MERGE, or DELETE statement that references some or all the CTE columns.

This change to the code above should work:

```
WITH nested AS
(
  SELECT e.my_id , SPLIT(secondary_ids, '<#>') AS arr_secondary_ids
  FROM table_with_delimited_string_column e
  WHERE my_id = 1234
) SELECT * FROM nested
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(nested.arr_secondary_ids) as unnested_output
```

If you do not want repetitions, try this:

```
SELECT my_id, unnested_output FROM 
(WITH nested AS
    (
      SELECT e.my_id , SPLIT(secondary_ids, '<#>') AS arr_secondary_ids
      FROM table_with_delimited_string_column e
      WHERE my_id = 1234
    ) SELECT * FROM nested
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(nested.arr_secondary_ids) as unnested_output
) as a;
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed your table reference after `FROM`

```
WITH nested AS
(
  SELECT e.my_id , SPLIT(secondary_ids, '<#>') AS arr_secondary_ids
  FROM table_with_delimited_string_column e
  WHERE my_id = 1234
)
SELECT DISTINCT a
FROM nested, UNNEST(arr_secondary_ids) a
```

Comment: Thanks @mikhail-berlyant . The way I see it, multiple tables in a FROM clause is syntactic sugar for a `CROSS JOIN`. Do you have any explanation on why including the parent table is required? I would like to avoid the CROSS JOIN as the table is quite big. Thanks.

Comment: in reality it is not regular cross join, rather flattening each row, so don't worry of table size. this is totally different from if you cross join two tables. as of sugar - you must specify table (in this case `nested` otherwise how bigquery will know the source of data. WITH statement just define CTE